# OrientDB: How can I create a property unique using SQL?

Tags: python, orientdb

I have a little question for you, I don't know how create a property UNIQUE. I know the SQL command for create a property, but don't know how do this UNIQUE.

And I can't use the app studio of OrientDB (would be most easy for me but...)

This is the command that I know:

```
"CREATE PROPERTY user.name STRING"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create index on this particular property.

```
CREATE INDEX user.name UNIQUE
```

Take a look here: [Console - CREATE INDEX](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Console-Command-Create-Index.html)

Comment: ok thank you so much. I'm nooby...-.- but... no need first create the property? If I create the index... will create the property at the same time?

Comment: Create the property first, then of course go with the index. Go and try it out, make mistakes, observe DB responses : )

Comment: I did, need to create property first... but... there isn't a command that create property and index the property? =S PiotrC thank u really so much